# Iterated integral evaluation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I was tasked to evaluate an iterated integral to find some volume and it seems that I can’t get it right.

The problem is: integral of square root of $x$ with $x$ limits $x=y^2$ to $x=2-y$ and $y$ limits $y=-2$ to $y=1$. Integrate with respect to $x$ first and then with respect to $y$.

$$\int_{-2}^1 \int_{y^2}^{2-y} \sqrt{x} dx dy$$

My answer is $\frac{323}{30}$ but the correct one should be $\frac{163}{30}$. I have used WolframAlpha integral calculator and it gave the right $\frac{163}{30}$ result. But Symbolab integral calculator gave $\frac{323}{30}$.

What is going on?

Comment: To learn how to typeset the math, look at this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}$ has an antiderivative $\frac23 x^{3/2}$, after integration over $x$, you get
$$
\int_{y^2}^{2-y} \sqrt{x} dx = 
\frac23\left((2-y)^{3/2} - (y^2)^{3/2}\right)
= \frac32\left((2-y)^{3/2} - |y|^3\right)$$

If your symbolic calculator simplifies $(y^2)^{3/2}$ to $y^3$ without checking whether $y$ is negative, you get $\frac{323}{30}$ instead of the correct answer $\frac{163}{30}$.

Comment: Thank you so much